# Create a new app for either iOS or Android using Flutter

Tags: flutter

How to create a new project using Flutter either for iOS or Android?

I tried with flutter create projectname but it is creating both iOS and Android platform.

Is it possible for any one platform?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `--platforms` parameter to specify which platforms you want to create the app for (defaults to all of them). So, if you want to create an app for only android you would do something like the following:

```
flutter create --platforms android my_app
```

Note: the `-i` and `-a` parameters are for selecting the language used, not restricting which platforms are generated.

Lastly: It does seem that you can simply delete the undesired platform directories after they are generated.

Comment: This is definitely the correct answer to what OP actually asked

Answer (score 2):

Just delete the `android` or `ios` folder created in the project.
You can also leave the folders and just not build for the platform you don't want to support.

Comment: thanks for reply, but is there any other way like when i create a new project i can give option either for iOS or Android to build.

Comment: What effect do you expect from it? If the app becomes an Android app or an iOS app is decided when you build like `flutter build apk` for Android or `flutter build ios` for iOS (or similar for debugging with `flutter run`). The directories `ios` and `android` just contain some support files for one platform.

Comment: Ok. Actually I would like to create only android app due to some functionalities does not support by iOS platform.

Comment: But you don't need to care. Even if you don't build for iOS in the end, there is no difference about how the project is created or developed. Why do you think you need to distinguish or decide when you create the project?

Answer (score 0):

The question is for creating a new project either for Android or iOS. Not for building.
Please follow the steps given in this tutorial [Get Started](https://flutter.io/setup-windows/#set-up-your-android-device).

In a nutshell

1. Get the Flutter SDK Update your path with flutter SDK
2. Run flutter doctor to make sure, flutter is installed correctly
3. Install the Flutter and Dart plugins for Android Studio
4. Create new flutter app by following this [tutorial](https://flutter.io/get-started/test-drive/)

Hope this helps

Comment: yes, i would like to create a new project only for Android due to some features does not support by iOS.

Comment: @gamerb I just formatted my answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create only Android or iOS project just run

(--ios-language select between swift or object-c)

```
flutter create  -i, --ios-language             [objc (default), swift]

flutter create  -a, --android-language         [java (default), kotlin]
```

Same for android